# How is possible translate a Custom Tab label in different languages?

Tags: custom-object, translation

is it possible to translate a custom object tab into multiple languages???

automate translation is not done for our custom object tabs...

How to fix this issue???
any one can help me.....

Answer (score 2):

This is managed in a different place, indeed.

go to `Setup->Customize->Tab Names and Labels->Rename Tabs and Labels`

At the top of the screen there's a '`Select Language'` dropdown. Select the language that you want to translate to and edit the labels in the screen below.

Custom Tabs are right below the Standard Tabs.

Comment: is there any other way to do automate translation for custom object tabs??

Comment: what exactly do you mean by automate? Since these are custom created objects, SF will not be able to provide a translation.  Or are you referring to export and import of the labels for processing by a translation agency?

Comment: ok, thanq.......

Comment: hi @Guy, I am interested if there are ways to export/import translation files for the custom and standard tabs and labels, just like how it's done in the translation workbench for custom fields, etc. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SamuelDev. It would be best if you post a new question for this on stackexchange, so any answers you will get can help others as well.

Comment: Thanks @Guy. As reference, here is the link to the question I raised, as per your advice -> [CLICK HERE](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/90262/how-to-translate-custom-tabs-and-labels-through-export-import-of-translation-fil)