# How to translate custom tabs and labels through export/import of translation files a la translation workbench

Tags: custom-field, tab, translation, customlabel, translation-workbench

I am interested if there are ways to export/import translation files for the custom and standard tabs and labels, just like how it's done in the translation workbench for custom fields, etc.

I already came from [this stackexchange post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56323/how-is-possible-translate-a-custom-tab-label-in-different-languages/56325?noredirect=1#comment119664_56325), but was told that it would be best to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab (retrieve) and export (deploy) easily all the translations of Standard and Custom Objects with all its Fields as well as Custom Applications and Custom Tabs from one org to another using the **Force.com Migration Tool**

Here some sample commands:

- ant retrieve -Dorg=sourceOrg_dev
- ant deployCheckOnly -Dorg=targetOrg_test
- ant deploy -Dorg=targetOrg_test

Check this on how to use the tool: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/

Here a sample file:

```
<types>
    <members>Account</members>
    <members>Contact</members>
    <members>Case</members>
    <members>CustomerRequest__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>

<types>
    <members>Account-de</members>
    <members>Contact-de</members>
    <members>Case-de</members>
    <members>CustomerRequest__c-de</members>
</types>

<types>
   <members>*</members>
   <name>CustomApplication</name>
</types>

<types>
   <members>*</members>
   <name>CustomLabels</name>
</types>

<types>
   <members>*</members>
   <name>CustomPageWebLink</name>
</types>

<types>
   <members>*</members>
   <name>CustomTab</name>
</types>

<types>
   <members>*</members>
    <name>Translations</name>
</types>

<version>34.0</version>
```

Comment: hmmm, interesting approach. I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce DX dramatically simplifies process of pulling declarative changes from Orgs.

When You do any declarative changes in Org, eg. You will add translation in workbench, then You just execute

`sfdx force:source:pull`

And dx will automatically detect all changed metadata, and pull it to Your codebase in 3 seconds.

As we started development using DX, all settings, xml configurations, demodata etc, etc we have in repository and they are automatically deployed on every new scratch org creation using very simple script consisting of about 6 commands. No more manual steps after refreshing sandbox!
I recommend everybody at least to give it a try.

PS. I am not salesforce sales-guy :)

Answer (score 0):

On the original attempt using the ant migration tool.  I do not understand this entry in the .xml file...

```
<types>
    <members>Account-de</members>
    <members>Contact-de</members>
    <members>Case-de</members>
    <members>CustomerRequest__c-de</members>
</types>
```

I surmise that "-de" is a language of suffix.  But should each block with in  have a  entry that identifies what type of metadata it is listing?